# RxJava/Android: Construct an Observable as the combination of original item and transformed item

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Here is the example:

```
Student[] students = ...;
Subscriber<Course> subscriber = new Subscriber<Course>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Course course) {
        Log.d(tag, course.getName());
    }
    ...
};
Observable.from(students)
    .flatMap(new Func1<Student, Observable<Course>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Course> call(Student student) {
            return Observable.from(student.getCourses());
        }
    })
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```

It's easy to observe courses, but what if I want to print out the pair of student-course? Is that necessary to change `Observable<Course>` to `Observable<Pair<Student, Course>>`? This method could be very tedious, because we could have multiple operators during transforming, but we don't want to keep the `Pairs` all the way transforming the observable.

Is that any other good way we can refer to the original item based on the transformed one?

Comment: If you simply want to print the student course pairs use the doOnNext operator.

Comment: @JohnWowUs Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goals and implementation you can use an overloaded variant of `flatMap` like this:

```
Observable.from(students)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Student, Observable<Course>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Course> call(Student student) {
                return Observable.from(student.getCourses());
            }
        }, new Func2<Student, Course, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call(Student student, Course course) {
                Log.d(tag, student + "->" + course.getName());
                return null;
            }
        })
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Well, in this way, we still have to keep student in every `flatMap()` or other operators. I'm afraid there is no big difference comparing to use `Pair<Student, transformedObject>`.

Comment: @shawn_wx well, there's no other operations in your question. Currently my solution does what you asked for: prints students and courses. You may want to add further requirements to your question.

Comment: I mentioned in my question, the reason I ask is I don't want to keep the original item (student) all the way during the transforming. If I just want to print out students and courses, I can use the Pair way.

Answer (score 0):

```
students.doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String student) {
                ArrayList<String> studentCourses = courses.get(student);
                for (int i=0 ; i<studentCourses.size() ; i++) {
                    System.out.println(student + " -> " + studentCourses.get(i) + " " + test);
                }
            }
        })
       .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) { /*System.out.println(s); */}

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) { }
       });
```

Comment: This just prints the pairs. Not very useful but it does what you asked for.